# Item-level permission preventing workflow emails from sending

Tags: workflow, item-level-permissions

I have a SharePoint list in O365 called 'Shift Requests' where employees can submit a request to do overtime by covering a vacant shift. I have a simple workflow in SP Designer that does the following:

Status = Pending - Sends an e-mail to a supervisor to alert them to the request

Status = Approved - Sends an email to the employee to advise them they can cover the shift

Status = Rejected - Send an email to the employee to advise them they cannot cover the shift

The 'pending' e-mail sends correctly each time, but I can only get the e-mails to send for the approved/rejected status when the level permissions are set to "Read all items" and "Create and edit all items".

Problem with this is it leaves the potential for unscrupulous employees to delete or edit other people's shift requests. Is there a way to fix this either with permissions or a workflow action please?